# Semi-Transparent elements always appear on top in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a `position:sticky` header on my website, and a disabled `select` element below it.
When I scroll down, so that the disabled `select` should be underneath the header, it appears on top of the header instead:

[image]
[image]

It seems to be happening with any element whose opacity is not 1, and the default style of a `disabled` select in Chrome is with partial opacity. This issue does not reproduce in Firefox.

How can I fix it, besides setting the opacity of the select to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `z-index: 999` to your header